# Adjacency list of a tree data structure in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following abstract data type defined in Haskell:

```
data Trie = Leaf
          | Node [(Char, Trie)]
          deriving (Eq)
```

The `Node` type is a list of elements `(c, t)` where `c` is the label for the edge from the current node to `t`.

Now I want to print out the adjacency list of the tree. Specifically, I need to print one edge per row, where an edge is in the format:

> n1 n2 c

with `n1` the source, `n2` the target, and `c` the label for the edge.

I can print the edges from my root node with

```
instance Show Trie where
    show = show' 2 1
        where show' _ _ Leaf = ""
              show' next n1 (Node ts) = unlines $ zipWith (\n2 (c, _) ->
                                                           show n1 ++ " " ++ show n2 ++ " " ++ show c)
                                                    [next..] ts
```

but now I'm stuck how to recursively print the children. In particular, how do I number the children nodes?

Comment: Is there a specific order you want to assign each node, or do you just want a unique number for each one? I would suggest writing your datatype as `data Trie a = Leaf | Node [(a, Trie)]` which should make it easy to write a function of type `Trie a -> Trie (a, Int)`

Comment: @user2407038 The root node needs to be numbered 1. The order for the rest doesn't matter as long as each node has a unique number.

Comment: @user2407038 I'm debating whether depth-first or breadth-first will be easier when writing `number :: Trie a -> Trie (a, Int)`.

Comment: @user2407038: Only that in this case you would number the _edges_, not the _nodes_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

enum :: Int -> Trie -> ([(Int,Int,Char)],Int)
enum x Leaf = ([],x+1)
enum x (Node pairs)
  = let go (acc,y) (c,t) = (acc',y')
          where acc' = [(x,y,c)] ++ edges ++ acc
                (edges,y') = enum y t
    in foldl' go ([],x+1) pairs
```

`enum` takes a starting id and a `Trie` and returns a list of edges and the next available id.

```
-- some examples:

leafs xs = [ (c,Leaf) | c <- xs ]
t1 = Node $ leafs "XYZ"
t2 = Node [('W', t1)]
t3 = Node $ [('A',t2)] ++ leafs "BC"

enum 1 t1 -- ([(1,4,'Z'),(1,3,'Y'),(1,2,'X')],5)
enum 1 t2 -- ([(1,2,'W'),(2,5,'Z'),(2,4,'Y'),(2,3,'X')],6)
enum 1 t3 -- ([(1,8,'C'),(1,7,'B'),(1,2,'A'),(2,3,'W'),(3,6,'Z'),(3,5,'Y'),(3,4,'X')],9)
```

Answer (score 5):

Labeling nodes is quite trivial since GHC will do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}

import qualified Data.Traversable as T
import qualified Data.Foldable as F 
import Control.Monad.State 

data Trie a = Leaf a | Node a [(Char, Trie a)] 
  deriving (Eq, Functor, F.Foldable, T.Traversable)

number :: Trie a -> Trie (a, Int)
number = flip evalState 1 . T.mapM (\x -> state $ \n -> ((x,n),n+1))
```

As for printing the trie, I'm afraid that I don't quite understand the desired output.

Comment: @user5402: sorry, I forgot to `flip`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
data Trie c =
    Leaf
  | Node [(c, Trie c)]
  deriving (Eq)

instance Show c => Show (Trie c) where
  show = show' 1 (\_ -> "\n") where
      show' next cc Leaf = show next ++ "\n” ++ cc (next + 1)
      show' next cc (Node []) = show next ++ "\n” ++ cc (next + 1)
      show' next cc (Node [(c,t)] = show c ++ "(" ++ show next ++ ")” ++ show' (next+1) cc t
      show' next cc (Node (x:xs)) = show' next (\n -> show' n cc $ Node xs) (Node [x])
```

I used continuation passing style to keep track of the state.  There should be a way of making that code monadic, or using a zipper instead.

You may change the specific bits for leaves or nodes depending on whether you need them to be numbered or not (by changing the `next + 1` part).